# Jquery toggle() and click() functions not working in internet explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my Jquery code.Please have a look through it and do help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#rec").click(function() {
    $("#tab1").toggle();
});
</script>
<input type="button" class="button" id="rec" value="Sample"/>
<div id="tab1">
Hello this is a sample jquery toggling function.
</div>
```

Comment: Might sound strange but try with jQuery version 2.x if it solves the issue then tell.

Comment: @user3751311 In a comment to an answer you mention that this code works in FF and Chrome, you should mention this in your question, as this will narrow down the problem. Are you sure that this is the exact order of your code because your sample should not work in FF and Chrome if the `script` tag with `$("#rec").click(function() {`  is placed before the element with the id `id="rec"`

Comment: place an `alert("hello!");` right before the `$("#tab1").toggle();` does it show when you click on `#rec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your Jquery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){})` as shown below :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#rec").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $("#tab1").toggle();
   });
 });
</script>
```

[Read More on `$(document).ready()` here.](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5LdLto4h/)

Comment: One of thse days I'll figure out why this error is so common. The first thing every jQuery tutorial shows is that you should do this.

Comment: The above code is working in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE !! What might be the problem?

Comment: @user3751311...it will in ie also..there may be there is issue somewhere else..see for any console errors in ie???

Comment: Please don't take me wrong . I'm new to this developing field . Could you please explain me what does console error mean? And how to fix that error?

Comment: @user3751311..just press f12 when you open your page in IE browser and then open console tab and then see the error over there.

Comment: @user3751311..strange...just download a latest version of jquery from here    http://jquery.com/download/   and try

Comment: see for any console errors and place an alert("hello!"); right before the $("#tab1").toggle(); does it show when you click on #rec???...@user3751311

Comment: The alert message(hello) is coming in Chrome and Firefox before toggling . . But its not coming in IE 11 !!

Comment: @user3751311...are you sure you are using IE11..i think you are using a older version of IE..????

Comment: Ya in Chrome the alert message is coming before the page gets loaded completely . But in IE alert message is not coming at all!!

Comment: Thanks a lot bro for spending your precious time in solving my problem :) :) Finally it is working :)

Comment: Yes of course it helped . . Thanks everyone and a big thanks to stack overflow for helping in solving the problem.

Comment: @SaGa Looks like your problem was solved by a ghost; what was it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an error while loading JQuery try this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Use `$(document).ready(function(){}`, to execute the js code when then document will be loaded or put your scripts just before the `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I ll take a ***guess*** here. (I'm feeling lucky!) (update:seems i wasn't lucky but read this anyway it's usefull)

Your code does not work because you say "do something when the html element with `id="rec"` is clicked" and "do something to the html element with `id="tab1"`"

My *guess* is, you have *more than one* html element with `id="rec"` and/or more than one html element with `id="tab1"` in your code.

`id` value of html elements must be unique across a webpage! If there are more than one html elements with the same `id` then the jquery selector doesn't know when to fire, and also browsers behavior can be unexpected. This may be the cause of internet explorer nagging.

Comment: But the same code is working in Chrome and Firefox??

Comment: @user3751311 duplicate ids can cause unexpected behavior. for example in a browser if you have many elements with same id, browser may think the first one is the real one. another browser may think the last one is the real one. another browser may just fail to load. so this can be the cause.

Comment: but as per the question posted by questioner i don't think there is any duplicate id's there.

Comment: @Kartikeya *HOW ON EARTH* you think this if you have no code available? You are not a good debugger :D (note that my answer is a guess ;) ). There are not few questions where jquery does not work, because... they havent LOADED the jquery lib! Expect anything when remotely-debugging! :D

Comment: ohhh...i just read your note late (that my answer is a wild guess) sorry for that..

Comment: No I haven't used any duplicate id's.. I rechecked my code.

Comment: @user3751311..just try using a latest jquery version ..i have provided the link in comment section below my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add compatibility meta just after `<head>` tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1" />
```

Comment: You should explain why you think that chaining the compatibility mode to `edge` would solve he problem.

Comment: Well if you have gone through this question and all posted answers you will see the issue is not clear and all code seems to be OK. P.S. if you need any explanation you should look into [html5 boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate) which recommended this.

Comment: I for sure know what `X-UA-Compatible` is about (If I wouldn't a direct link to the FAQ would be more helpful then just a link to the root of the repos). And I also see that the question is not clear. But you should at least explain why adding `X-UA-Compatible` might help.